# combing two SELECT statements into a JOIN

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have two tables: table_1: `item_id`, `name` ...  table_2: `image_id`, `item_id`, `url`

The following function retrieves the 'urls' of the items with the '$name' that is passed in. I first need to get the 'item_id' from table_1 to use in the query. I only need to return the 'url's from table_2.

It currently works fine, but I feel it could be streamlined to be done in one query with a JOIN rather than two separate queries. I've tried using different 'JOIN's to make it work but I can't seem to get it right.

Here's the function as it stands now with the two queries...

```
function get_items( $name ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $sql1 = "SELECT `item_id` FROM `table_1` WHERE `name` = '$name'";
    $results1 = $wpdb->get_var( $sql1 );

    $sql1 = "SELECT `url` FROM `table_2` WHERE `item_id` = '$results1'";
    $results2 = $wpdb->get_results( $sql1, ARRAY_A );

    return $results2;

}
```

and here is the 'JOIN' that I tried implementing, but was unsuccessful (I've also switched it around and did a 'LEFT/RIGHT JOIN' as well resulting in the same result) ...

```
$sql1 = "SELECT `table_2`.`url` 
         FROM `table_2` 
         INNER JOIN `table_1`
         ON `table_2`.`item_id` = `table_1`.`item_id`
         WHERE `table_1`.`item_id` = '$name'";
```

Any advice on combining these two queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is this `WHERE table_1.item_id = '$name'`, it should be the `name` not the `item_id`

```
SELECT  b.url
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.item_id = b.item_id
WHERE   a.name = '$name'
```

Comment: Did you mean `a.name = '$name'`?

Comment: Wow! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select url from table_2 where item_id IN (select item_id from table_1 where name = $name )
```

Comment: This would work, but is not a very good way to do it. A join would be faster.

Comment: probably yeah.. but i vaguely remember reading somewhere that during query optimisation stage Nesting is optimised to joins internally thus resulting in equivalent performance. I agree that even if thats true, there is an overhead of query optimizer.